# Fill 'As Workbook' variable with 'As String' variable

Tags: vba, excel

My VBA project has a dynamic name since it contains e.g. the 'version number'.
But I would like to refer to 1 of its sheets from another workbook (that workbook has been created by my project to do the work in there).

I have this code and that works, but it is not dynamically:

```
   Dim ProjectPathName As String
    Dim ProjectPathNameLength As Integer
    Dim ProjectFileName As String
    Dim PosLastBackSlash As Integer
    Dim RDXX As Workbook

    ProjectPathName = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.FileName
    ProjectPathNameLength = Len(ProjectPathName)
    PosLastBackSlash = InStrRev(ProjectPathName, "\")
    ProjectFileName = Right(ProjectPathName, (ProjectPathNameLength - PosLastBackSlash))

    Set RDXX = Workbooks("RDXX 2017-10_2_DEV.xlam")
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
'    Set wbDeltaWorks = Workbooks(FileName:=ProjectFileName)
    '   Set wbDeltaWorks = Workbooks(FileName = ProjectFileName)
    '    Set wbDeltaWorks = Workbooks(ProjectFileName)
    '    Set wbDeltaWorks = Workbooks("ProjectFileName")
    '    Set wbDeltaWorks = Workbooks("" & ProjectFileName & "")
    '    Set wbDeltaWorks = Workbooks(""" & ProjectFileName & """)
    '    Set wbDeltaWorks = Workbooks(ProjectFileName.Value)
    '    Set wbDeltaWorks = Workbooks(1)
    '    Set wbDeltaWorks = ProjectFileName
```

Can you help me on this?

All help is much appreciated!

Comment: `Set wbDeltaWorks = Workbooks(ProjectFileName)` should work assuming the name is correct and it includes the extension.

Comment: You can get workbook name in more straightforward manner like this: `ProjectFileName = Dir(ProjectPathName)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the iteration numbers are at the end of the project name. Lets say the current iteration is called "myProject_1234". You can loop through all open workbooks via the [Windows collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224503(v=office.11).aspx) and look for that keyword:

```
For Each Window In Application.Windows

    If Left(Window.Caption, 9) = "myProject" Then
        Set myWorkbook = Application.Workbooks(Window.Caption)
        Exit For
    End If

Next Window
```

If the numbers aren't at the end or you'd prefer not to use the [Left function](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/left.php) use the [Instr function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1(v=vs.90).aspx) instead, the principle is the same.

Comment: I think the method to be OK, but OP wants to parse the VBA project name, so the condition might be `If Left(Workbooks(Window.Caption).VBProject.Name, 9) = "myProject" Then`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, it got me on the right track! I went for what Rory said, since that already worked "the Set wbDeltaWorks = Workbooks(ProjectFileName) should work assuming the name is correct and it includes the extension.".
I only used it to late in the process at a stage where another workbook was active. Therefore I got the wrong project name.

thanks again!